I want to use Enum class inside the withcolumn of a Pyspark UDF
I have a Dataframe inputDF with multiple columns, out of which productcode is one of the column ,I want to check the values of the column productcode  with evaluating it with the enum class product_code which is present in a different folder so am importing it with using from common.codes.product_code import product_code if the column  productcode has values apart from the ones defined in the enum class then it should write False in the new column enum_column
When I run this code am getting "Error: '{enum_type}' is not a valid Enum class."
when it evaluates globals().get(enum_type) am getting enum_class as None not sure why
from common.codes.product_code import product_code

def use_enum_in_method(enum_type,value):
    enum_class = globals().get(enum_type)
    if enum_class is None or not issubclass(enum_class, Enum):
        print(f"Error: '{enum_type}' is not a valid Enum class.")
        return False
    else:
        values_list = [member.value for member in enum_class]
        if value not in values_list:
            return False
        else:
            return True

validate_enum = udf(lambda a,value: use_enum_in_method(a,value), BooleanType())
df = inputDF.withColumn("enum_column",validate_enum(lit("product_code".lower()),"productcode"))
df.show()

from enum import Enum

class product_code(Enum):
    CEP = "CEP"
    COF = "COF"
    HMO = "HMO"
    MC = "MC"
    MCF = "MCF"
    MCR = "MCR"
    MCS = "MCS"
    MD = "MD"
    MDE = "MDE"
    MEP = "MEP"
    MLI = "MLI"
    MMO = "MMO"
    MMP = "MMP"
    MOS = "MOS"
    MP = "MP"
    MPO = "MPO"
    MR = "MR"
    MRB = "MRB"
    MRF = "MRF"
    MRS = "MRS"
    POS = "POS"
    PPO = "PPO"
    SN1 = "SN1"
    SN2 = "SN2"
    SN3 = "SN3"
    SN4 = "SN4"
    SN5 = "SN5"
    SN6 = "SN6"
    M99 = "M99"
    MCL = "MCL"


Is the name of column you mentioned "productcode" or "product_code"?

lit("product_code".lower() is the enum class name "productcode" is the column name

Add print(type(enum_type), enum_type) inside use_enum_in_method and print(type(product_code), product_code) after df.show(), and see what it would say.

print(type(enum_type), enum_type) --> it prints <class 'str'> product_code and for print(type(product_code), product_code) --> <class 'enum.EnumMeta'> <enum 'product_code'>

Seems right. Strange.

please suggest if there is some other to do this requirement


Add print(type(enum_class), enum_class) after enum_class = globals().get(enum_type) to see if the result is None or something other than product_code. 2. Add print("validate_enum" in globals()) before  enum_class = globals().get(enum_type) to see if globals gets shadowed. Both seem very unlikely.


enum_class shows as None and print("validate_enum" in globals()) shows false.When I print globals alone it has <enum 'product_code'> but still enum_class shows as None

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I've not been able to join the chat (probably caused by network condition). After reading the source code, as a partial result, I can tell you that Pyspark DOES alter __globals__ on some of your functions, so that anything in the global scope that is not explicitly read or written will be non-existing (in order for the function to be pickled). I'm not sure that's the cause for your case, but it looks highly possible. As a validation, print(id(globals())) in and out of your udf, if the results differed, my guess would be confirmed.

I have printed  print(id(globals())) before and after calling the udf both shows the same value but the one printed inside the use_enum_in_method,shows different values
